# C# - Not getting Color[] values in Deserialization

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, xml-serialization

I am serializing an array of `Color[]`. Assigning some values of `Color` to it at the time of serializing.

```
ColorList = new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Black, Color.Yellow };
```

At the time of deserialization, I am getting the object back with same array length but the values aren't there. 
Here is what I am getting -

```
{Name=0, ARGB=(0, 0, 0, 0)}
```

Comment: does [this answer help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2306335/5174469) ? or may be [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3891614/5174469) ?

Comment: Serializing to what?

Comment: @haim770 XML serialization

Comment: Assuming you are using `XmlSerializer` then I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4322461/3744182) is the best answer to this question.

Comment: Which serializer are you using - `XmlSerializer` or `DataContractSerializer`?

Answer (score 1):

`System.Drawing.Color` cannot be represented as `RGBA` upon serialization. You need to represent it as a color code, and de-code it later on.

You would have to use a `string` array with the RGBA values like this:

```
ColorList = new string[] { 
    string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", Color.Red.R, Color.Red.G, Color.Red.B, Color.Red.A),
    string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", Color.Black.R, Color.Black.G, Color.Black.B, Color.Black.A),
    string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", Color.Yellow.R, Color.Yellow.G, Color.Yellow.B, Color.Yellow .A)
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me the reason behind it?

Comment: Color cannot be represented as RGBA upon serialization. You need to represent it as a color code, and de-code it later on.

Comment: `ColorTranslator.ToHtml` and `ColorTranslator.FromHtml` would be simpler